# Parsing HTML with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a tuple defined with the keywords of links that I'm interested in a given page, so:

```
categories = ('car', 'planes', ...)
```

I'm trying to get into a list all links inside a given class that matches any value of my category tuple. The document is as following:

```
<div class='content'>
    <ul class='side-panel'>
        <li><a href='page1.html'>page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href='page2.html'>page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href='best_car_2013.html'>Best Cars</a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

for now I'm doing:

```
found = []

for link in soup.find_all(class_='side-panel'):
    for category in categories:
        if re.search(category, link.get('href')):
            found.append(link)
```

I get a type error "expected string or buffer". Debugging the script, I know that I'm getting all 'li' with their respective anchor tags but I'm having trouble iterating on all this resultset to get the 'href' of each link that matches my tuple inside a list.

Comment: posting the full exception trace would be helpful.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wallscraper.py", line 31, in <module>
    if re.search(category, link.get('href')):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 142, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: Add `href=True` to the `find_all()` otherwise `link.get('href')` may return `None` and `re.search()` expects a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you find yourself manually iterating over tags to do some additional filtering, it's usually better to just use the `bs4` API instead.  In this case, you can pass a regex to `find_all`.

```
soup.find(class_='side-panel').find_all(href=re.compile('|'.join(categories)))
Out[86]: [<a href="best_car_2013.html">Best Cars</a>]
```

If it's unclear, joining `categories` with pipes into one expression lets the `re` engine decide if *any* of the categories match the href attribute.  This replaces explicitly looping over each category and individually doing a `re` search.

**edit**: (referring to link in comments) it looks like the page you're scraping has *two* `class='side-panel categories'` tags (???) so a loop over the initial `find_all` operation doing more `find_all` operations is probably appropriate:

```
[t for tags in soup.find_all(class_='side-panel categories') 
    for t in tags.find_all(href=re.compile('|'.join(selected_links)))]
Out[24]: 
[<a href="/animals__birds-desktop-wallpapers.html">Animals &amp; Birds</a>,
 <a href="/beach-desktop-wallpapers.html">Beach</a>,
 <a href="/bikes__motorcycles-desktop-wallpapers.html">Bikes</a>,
 <a href="/cars-desktop-wallpapers.html">Cars</a>,
 <a href="/digital_universe-desktop-wallpapers.html">Digital Universe</a>,
 <a href="/flowers-desktop-wallpapers.html">Flowers</a>,
 <a href="/nature__landscape-desktop-wallpapers.html">Nature</a>,
 <a href="/planes-desktop-wallpapers.html">Planes</a>,
 <a href="/travel__world-desktop-wallpapers.html">Travel &amp; World</a>,
 <a href="/vector__designs-desktop-wallpapers.html">Vector &amp; Designs</a>]
```

Comment: Hmm... I didn't quite get it. I don't know before hand the full link. I just have a tuple with keywords, and I want all links in a given class that matches one of my keywords.

Comment: I'm just getting an empty list. Please, see my entire code here: http://pastebin.com/YCN5X7Wj

Comment: @XVirtusX: don't put your code into pastebin. [Update your question instead](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22287079/edit) or ask a new one.

Comment: @XVirtusX I looked at the page you're scraping.  There are multiple `side-panel categories` tags so `find_all` is needed in lieu of `find`.